# Send mail with large attachment?

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking to use the graph API to send emails with large attachments (up to 20MB). Is there any way of sending emails with large attachments?

Previous attempts with the Graph lead to the discovery of a 4MB upload limit. I had alternatively also looked into uploading a file to OneDrive and attaching it by reference but I believe that runs into the same 4MB limit.

This limit rules out Microsoft Graph.

I have heard that the legacy Outlook REST API is capable of handling large file uploads, however, I can't find any way of getting access to the Outlook REST API today, it looks like it has been deprecated. Additionally, all documentation I read from Microsoft very quickly encourages you onto the new Graph API instead.

Looking at the Azure Portal there seems to be no way of allowing my application to get authenticated to the Outlook API, it's not an option anywhere.

For reference here is the relevant snippet I've been using with the Graph API.

```
$mailBody = ...
'attachments' => [
    [
        '@odata.type' => '#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment',
        'Name' => 'file.docx',
        'ContentBytes' => $localFile
    ]
 ]
     ...

$response = $this->getGraph()->createRequest("POST", "/users/{primary-user}/sendMail")
                ->attachBody($mailBody)
                ->execute();
```

Comment: You can upload files to OneDrive larger than 4MB, but you have to make multiple requests. See this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: You are using PHP, so you have a webserver. Can you not host the files on your webserver and merely send a download link? You can write a `download.php` script that serves a file and, once it has been accessed/downloaded, deletes it from your webserver.

Comment: Download links can be problematic given how often IT departments have been drilling "never click links in an email" into everyone's head for the past few years. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upload files larger than 4MB to OneDrive using an [Upload Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0). Instead of sending the entire file all at once, an upload session allows you to send the file in chunks. Once the entire file has been uploaded, the session is closed and the file becomes available on the Drive.

Once you have the file uploaded to OneDrive, you can attach it to an email as a [`referenceAttachment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/referenceattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0).

You'll also want to use the distinct [Create Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0), [Update Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0), and [Send Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0) methods instead of the simplified `sendMail`. So your workflow will look something like this:

1. [Create the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0) (`POST /users/{id}/messages`):
2. [Add the attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0) (`POST /users/{id}/messages/{id}/attachments`)
3. [Send the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0) (`POST /users/{id}/messages/{id}/send`)

---

There is a common misconception that the Outlook REST API is an entirely different API from Microsoft Graph. While there are certainly some features of the Outlook REST API that haven't been exposed on the Graph yet, they are the same API behind the scenes.

Microsoft Graph is really an API aggregator rather than an API itself (useless trivia: Graph often referred by the acronym  AGS for "Aggregator Service"). For basic calls, Graph simply routes the call to the underlying API and rewrites the response in a normalized OData format. Where Graph gets interesting is in more complex calls where it can do things like route calls to multiple underlying APIs and then merge the results together.

If you're currious what it's doing, you can add `?whatif` to your call and Graph will return the underlying workload it's routing too instead of the actual results (i.e. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?whatif`).